# How do I implement a tensorflow_datasets.feature.Sequence() of BBoxes? (Could not build a TypeSpec [BBox()] with type 'list)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to extend the functionality of the ImageFolder builder (https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/blob/master/tensorflow_datasets/core/folder_dataset/image_folder.py#L41-L173)
to include and read the .txt bounding box files in the OpenImagesV6 dataset. This is my customized DatasetInfo:

```
    return dataset_info.DatasetInfo(
        builder=self,
        description='Generic image classification dataset.',
        features=features_lib.FeaturesDict({
            'image': features_lib.Image(
                shape=self._image_shape,
                dtype=self._image_dtype,
            ),
            'label': features_lib.ClassLabel(num_classes=3),
            'image/filename': features_lib.Text(),
            'bbox_path': features_lib.Text(),
            'bboxes': features_lib.Sequence({
                'bbox': features_lib.BBoxFeature()
              }),
        }),
        supervised_keys=('image', 'label'),
    )
```

In the _as_dataset function, I've succesfullly made a Dataset with from_tensor_slices, but when I try to map the _load_and_decode_fn to the Dataset to read the image and bbox files, when _load_example tries to return the dict I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for [BBox(ymin=<tf.Tensor 'while/StringToNumber_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, xmin=<tf.Tensor 'while/StringToNumber:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, ymax=<tf.Tensor 'while/StringToNumber_3:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, xmax=<tf.Tensor 'while/StringToNumber_2:0' shape=() dtype=float32>)] with type list
```

This is my modified _load_example function:

```
def _load_example(
    path: tf.Tensor,
    label: tf.Tensor,
    bbox_path: tf.Tensor,

) -> Dict[str, tf.Tensor]:
  
  bbox_values = tf.io.read_file(bbox_path)
  bbox_values = tf.strings.split(bbox_values, sep='\n')
  bboxes = []
  for line in bbox_values:
      line = tf.strings.split(line, sep=' ')
      if line[0] is not None:
        xmin = tf.strings.to_number(line[1])
        ymin = tf.strings.to_number(line[2])
        xmax = tf.strings.to_number(line[3])
        ymax = tf.strings.to_number(line[4])

        bboxes.append(features_lib.BBox(
          ymin=ymin, 
          xmin=xmin, 
          ymax=ymax, 
          xmax=xmax
         ))
  img = tf.io.read_file(path)
  return {
      'image': img,
      'label': tf.cast(label, tf.int64),
      'image/filename': path,
      'bbox_path': bbox_path,
      'bboxes': {
        'bbox': bboxes
      }
  }
```

I must be missing something fairly basic here. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding how the map function works?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood how Tensors work in a map function. I loaded the bbox data before creating the dataset, and then changed _as_dataset() to use load_from_generator() instead of _load_from_tensor_slices(). That, and proper designation of types and shapes solved my problem.